# javascript addEventListener is applying on all elements

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my js function. When I click on one post-card, all elements are showing the menu. What do I need to change in the function so it only shows the menu of the card that is clicked? Any help is appreciated.

html:

```
        <div class="container-posts-card">
            <img src = "" class = "container-post-card-img">
            <p class = "container-post-card-caption"></p>
            <div class="posts_card_edit">
                <span class = "ellipsis-edit"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="card_edit_options">
                <a href= "" >Edit</a>
                <a href= "" >Delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

js:

```
let cardEdit = document.getElementsByClassName("posts_card_edit");
let cardOP = document.getElementsByClassName("card_edit_options");
for(var i = 0; i < cardEdit.length; i++){
    cardEdit[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
        for(var j = 0; j < cardOP.length; j ++){
            if(cardOP[j].style.display === "none"){
                cardOP[j].style.display = "flex"
            }else{
                cardOP[j].style.display = "none"
            }
        }
    })
}
```

[image]

Comment: You have a loop through all `cardOP`, why? This is causing the trouble. You need to grab only the nearest one right? Let's give it a shot, try some solution.

Comment: I think I have to use a loop for cardOP because there are many elements by that class name, otherwise (cardOP.style is undefined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be simplified alot. What you want to show is each `nextElementSibling` when clicked:

```
const cardEdits = document.querySelectorAll(".posts_card_edit");
for (const cardEdit of cardEdits){
    cardEdit.addEventListener('click', function() {
        const cardOP = cardEdit.nextElementSibling;
        cardOP.style.display = cardOP.style.display === "none" ? "flex" : "none";
    })
}
```

Comment: With that code onclick only on the last card is showing the menu cardOp.

Comment: @makz There was a `const` keyword missing in the for loop. Corrected now.